# building empty filter driver with vs 2015 and wdk 10 fails

Tags: build, visual-studio-2015, wdk, minifilter

I couldn't imagine, just how hard it can be for me to start building a sample minifilter driver using vs 2015 and wdk 10!

I've had 2013 running on my pc, then received a swapbuffer sample configured for 8.1. I simply installed WDK 8.1 from Microsoft and that's all. it compiled.
But when I tried to build a minifilter driver using wdk10 everything got hard as hell.

everything is done as this guy said in [here](http://www.windrvr.com/2015/05/11/wdk-installation-tips/) and I am on a virtual machine running windows 10.

after installation and that and that and repairing this and that ... when I create an empty fsfilter driver project using vs sample project, build fails with this error:

"An SDK corresponding to WDK version '8.1' was not found. Please install the SDK before building."
This error refers to the file windowsDriver.common.targets in tis line:

```
<Error Text="An SDK corresponding to WDK version '$(TargetPlatformVersion)' was not found. Please install the SDK before building."
       Condition="'$(MatchingSdkPresent)' != 'true'" />
```

can somebody give me a hint on how to solve this issue?!

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10 WDK requires matching SDK version to be installed. Looks like the default for the project you created is falling back to 8.1.

In the project properties, look for Configuration Properties -> General -> "Target Platform version" drop down and select the 10.0.10XXX.0 and try to build it.

If you have installed the latest version of WDK(10.0.105860.0) then make sure the corresponding SDK is installed too. You can check this in the VS installer to see if "Tools (1.2) and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586)" under "Universal Windows App Development Tools" is selected.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
After much mucking about it turns out that the WDK is not enough; you also need to install the latest Windows 10 SDK which does *not* by default get installed or updated with Visual Studio. I thought it did, (I've got VS2015, Update 3) but clearly it doesn't. I got the latest version from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk
, retargeted my project to the latest version (at the time of writing that is 10.0.14393.0), and both the 10 year old sample and the VS wizzard generated projects now work (at least the small sample I've tried.)